# Change vim shortcut

Tags: linux, vim, keyboard-shortcuts, text-editor

I have a [bepo](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/05/KB_French_Dvorak_b%C3%A9po_simplifi%C3%A9.svg) keyboard and the problem with it, is that I can't properly use the hjkl keys to move.
I would like to change these shortcuts to ctsr instead. How can I do that.

Thank you for your answers in advance.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:map` to map a sequence of keys to execute another sequence of keys as described [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_(Part_1))